# Почему идет разное поведение веб-формы на разных страницах

Tags: битрикс

Есть форма:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Одна страница. набираешь телефон и кликаешь на кнопку "отправить".  Появляется окошко "Заявка оптравлена успешно"
Вторая страница: действия такие же, но появляется окно , в котором включен весь сайт

```html
  <div style="margin-left: 18px; margin-top: 4px;">
                 <div id="call_show" class="css_popup btn btn-warning" style="text-decoration:underline">
                  <a>
                         <img src="/img_new/phone_icon.png" height="16" width="13" alt="">
                         <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #999999; position: relative; top: -3px;">Позвоните мне</span>
                   </a>
                   </div>
                 
              </div>
<?CJSCore::Init(array("popup", "jquery", "ajax"));?>
<script>
 BX.ready(function(){
  var oPopup = new BX.PopupWindow('callback-popup', window.body, {
   autoHide : true,
   offsetTop : 1,
   offsetLeft : 0,
   lightShadow : true,
   closeIcon : true,
   closeByEsc : true,
   overlay: {
    backgroundColor: 'black', opacity: '80'
   }
  });

  oPopup.setContent(BX('request_call'));

  BX.bindDelegate(
   document.body, 'click', {className: 'css_popup' },
   BX.proxy(function(e){
    if(!e)
     e = window.event;
    oPopup.show();
    return BX.PreventDefault(e);
   }, oPopup)
  );
 });
</script>

<div id="request_call">
 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
 "bitrix:form.result.new",
 "form_call_me",
 Array(
  "AJAX_MODE" => "Y",
  "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
  "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
  "AJAX_OPTION_SHADOW" => "N",
  "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
  "CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
  "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
  "CHAIN_ITEM_LINK" => "",
  "CHAIN_ITEM_TEXT" => "",
  "EDIT_URL" => "",
  "IGNORE_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE" => "N",
  "LIST_URL" => "",
  "SEF_MODE" => "N",
  "SUCCESS_URL" => "",
  "USE_EXTENDED_ERRORS" => "Y",
  "VARIABLE_ALIASES" => array("WEB_FORM_ID"=>"WEB_FORM_ID","RESULT_ID"=>"RESULT_ID",),
  "WEB_FORM_ID" => "26"
 )
);?>
</div>
```

сама компонента

```html
<?
if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
?>

<div class="callback-popup">
 <div class="callback-popup-content_default">
  <?/* ?>
  <div class="callback-popup-content_success">
   <?=$arResult["FORM_NOTE"]?>
  </div>
  <? */?>
  <?if ($arResult["isFormNote"] == "Y"){?>
   <div class="success"><?=GetMessage('FORM_SEND_SUCCESS')?></div>
  <?}else{?>
   <?=$arResult["FORM_HEADER"]?>
   <?if($arResult["isFormTitle"]){?><h3><?=$arResult["FORM_TITLE"]?></h3><?}?>
   <?if ($arResult["isFormErrors"] == "Y"):?><p class="callback-errors"><?=$arResult["FORM_ERRORS_TEXT"];?></p><?endif;?>
<table class="data-table">
 <tbody>
 <?
 foreach ($arResult["QUESTIONS"] as $FIELD_SID => $arQuestion)
 {
  if ($arQuestion['STRUCTURE'][0]['FIELD_TYPE'] == 'hidden')
  {
   echo $arQuestion["HTML_CODE"];
  }
  else
  {
 ?>
  <tr>
   <td width="200px">
    <?if (is_array($arResult["FORM_ERRORS"]) && array_key_exists($FIELD_SID, $arResult['FORM_ERRORS'])):?>
    <span title="<?=$arResult["FORM_ERRORS"][$FIELD_SID]?>"></span>
    <?endif;?>
    <?=$arQuestion["CAPTION"]?><?if ($arQuestion["REQUIRED"] == "Y"):?><?=$arResult["REQUIRED_SIGN"];?><?endif;?>
    <?=$arQuestion["IS_INPUT_CAPTION_IMAGE"] == "Y" ? "<br />".$arQuestion["IMAGE"]["HTML_CODE"] : ""?>
   </td>
   <td class="<?=$FIELD_SID?>"><?=$arQuestion["HTML_CODE"]?></td>
  </tr>
 <?
  }
 } //endwhile
 ?>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <th colspan="2" align="center">
    <button <?=(intval($arResult["F_RIGHT"]) < 10 ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : "");?> class="button bt3" type="submit" name="web_form_submit" value="<?=htmlspecialcharsbx(strlen(trim($arResult["arForm"]["BUTTON"])) <= 0 ? GetMessage("FORM_ADD") : $arResult["arForm"]["BUTTON"]);?>">
     <span><?=htmlspecialcharsbx(strlen(trim($arResult["arForm"]["BUTTON"])) <= 0 ? GetMessage("FORM_ADD") : $arResult["arForm"]["BUTTON"]);?></span>
    </button>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
<?=$arResult["REQUIRED_SIGN"];?> - <?=GetMessage("FORM_REQUIRED_FIELDS")?>
</p>
<?=$arResult["FORM_FOOTER"]?>
<?
} //endif (isFormNote)
?>
 </div>
</div>
```

и еще жк код, которые есть в этой компоненте component_epilog.php

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
<?$bxajaxid = CAjax::GetComponentID($component->__name, $component->__template->__name);?>
<style>#wait_comp_<?=$bxajaxid?>{display: none !important;}</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[name = CALL_ME]').submit(function(){
        return formOrderCheck(this);
    });

       $('.PHONE input[type=text]').mask('+9(999)999-99-99');
});


function formOrderCheck(form)
{
    var success = true;
    var phone = $(form).find('.PHONE input[type = text]');
    
    if(!$(phone).val())
    {
        $(phone).parent('td').addClass('error');
        success = false;
    }
    else
        $(phone).parent('td').removeClass('error');
    
    return success;
}

</script>
```

UPD:
 стала смотреть на странице, где возникает ошибка попапа, в консоли [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если появляется окно в котором "код сайта" возвращает, значит такой ответ выдает сервер, смотрите жс код который реагирует на действие кнопки

Comment: Какой в этом случае ответ выдает сервер, если появляется окно, в котором код сайта?  я обновила код, посмотрите, пожалуйста, никакого жк кода я не вижу.

Comment: причем существует разное поведение на двух страницах

Comment: Можно консолькой отбить что срабатывает, и смотреть.

Comment: какая ошибка в консоли? Скажите, пож-ста